# Mouse clicks ignored on modal JDialog

Tags: java, swing, modal-dialog, jdialog

I'm having trouble understanding the behaviour of a modal JDialog.

When the dialog is set to visible all works fine until the user clicks back on the parent JFrame that was used to launch it.  Although the dialog remains on top as expected, all subsequent mouse clicks back on the JDialog are ignored.  The form items in the JDialog can still be filled in, but only if you navigate using tab.  Is this normal or am I missing something obvious?

Below is a simple example that illustrates the behaviour:

```java
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dialog.ModalityType;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class TestApp {

private JFrame frame;

    public TestApp() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JButton btnRun = new JButton("run");
        btnRun.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                JDialog dialog = getChildDialog();
                dialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
                dialog.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
        frame.getContentPane().add(btnRun, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }

    public JDialog getChildDialog() {

        JDialog dialog = new JDialog();
        dialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
        dialog.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(new JTextField(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Blah"), BorderLayout.EAST);
        panel.add(new JLabel("Blah"), BorderLayout.WEST);
        dialog.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        dialog.getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        return dialog;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try {
                    TestApp window = new TestApp();
                    window.frame.setVisible(true);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same behaviour even when the JDialog is a JOptionPane.  So you can make the above code simpler by replacing the getChildDialog() with JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "blah")

Comment: your example code throws a error at line 27 `dialog.setModalityType(ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODEL)`

Comment: Sorry @Rubinum.  It was simply missing an import statement.  I had changed from the deprecated setModel() to setModalityType() without rechecking it compiled.

Comment: The code works fine for me using JDK7_60 on Windows 7. The only thing I can suggest is to specify the frame as the parent when you create the dialog.

Comment: I tried your code and my clicks worked on the components without using tab. did i miss something or do i missunderstand?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback.  I think this must be a bug in the JVM I'm using (OpenJDK 2.4.7 7u55-2.4.7-1ubuntu1).

I've just run the same code on a Windows Java 7 JVM and don't get the same behaviour.  I will submit a bug report.